# Allow for Custom Show Logo and background image for Roku Channel

Tags: roku

Hopefully a quick link answer here, need to find out how to create a custom logo and background for each show on client's Roku Channel.  So when scrolling through channels the background image will change for each show and display the name of the show with a custom image/logo for the show.  Any ideas?

Comment: Will this scrolling behavior be when the item is focused on during scroll?

Comment: Correct.  it doesn’t necessarily need to be like Hulu’s interface where a vertical scroll is how everything highlights, but that would be awesome if it’s possible.  I’m assuming we need to do this custom and can’t achieve this via the direct publish templates correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the `itemSelected` field of the list or grid you're scrolling through. Let's call it `m.listPanel`. You'd set up this observer like this:

`m.listPanel.observeField("itemSelected", "updateBackground")`

then, in order to change the background, you'd need some kind of array with all the content (image, logo, title, etc) associated with each show, in the same order as the list. Let's call it `m.contents`. When the selected index changes, grab the appropriate contents and add them to some kind of background. Here I'm using a rectangle. Then insert this background before the children you would like to be drawn on top of it. Here I am inserting it all the way behind everything else, at position 0.

```
sub updateBackground(event as object)
    index = event.getData()
    backgroundContent = m.contents[index]
    rectangle = createObject("roSGNode", "rectangle")
    label = createObject("roSGNode","Label")
    label.text = backgroundContent.title
    poster = createObject("roSGNode", "Poster")
    poster.uri = backgroundContent.hdPosterUrl
    rectangle.appendChild(poster)
    rectangle.appendChild(label)
    m.top.insertChild(0, rectangle)
end sub
```

obviously this isn't perfect, you'd need to get rid of the old background as well. Or maybe have an m.backgroundRect where you change fields rather than creating new ones, but I hope this gives you a start.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Any thoughts on the logo for the show itself or do these other guys do it by putting the logo on the background image itself....which may be in fact easier.

Comment: You'd need a second Poster node for the logo. In SceneGraph, nodes added to the scene are drawn on top of nodes already there, so just make sure to append the Poster with the logo after the one with the background and you should be fine. Play around with the translation field until the logo shows where you want it.